# ARCore. Rotate a 3D object according to camera's orientation in the real world

Tags: android, arcore

I'm trying to render a 3D object (an arrow) and rotate it according to camera rotation in the real world.
I'm thinking of using Camera method : getPose().getRotationQuaternion([]float), transform the qy in degrees and then apply the rotation matrix.
But i can't understand how to use quaternions and if this is the right way to reach my goal.
Thank you.

Comment: I would also like to know how to do this. Quaternions are very complicated and not something that most programmers could use easily. Google should really cook these down to roll, yaw, pitch, and translations for the ARCore API if they want to promote it...

Comment: @YinOrYan if you are still interested i solved in this way: I extracted the Camera quaternions from its Pose with getRotationQuaternions(), then I created an array of quaternions float[4] = {0 , qycamera, 0, 0} and used Pose.makeRotation(float[] quaternions).toMatrix(float[], init index) to extract the rotation matrix around y axis like the camera ones.Then i multiply my 3Dobject model matrix x this rotation matrix in order to obtain the right rotation